# How can I check the the domain of the website that sent a get method request php

Tags: php, get, cross-domain

So if I have two websites

`www.example.com`

and

`www.api.com`

and `www.example.com` makes a get request to `www.api.com`, how would I be able to check if it was legitimately `www.example.com`? I was going to send `www.example.com` as one of the variables, but then if the user really wanted to they could just change the variable to `$site = 'www.example.com';` I was wondering if there was a way that on `www.api.com` I would be able to grab the domain name of the site that submitted the request. Thanks.

This is for an api script I'm trying to make to check for a key and a domain to ensure that license is active. Thank you!

Comment: try this http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **HTTP_REFERER** from the `$_SERVER` global.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Keep in mind that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value can be faked.

Answer (score 0):

In an http request, you will only get the IP of the request, not a domain name.

Comment: is there any way I could convert that ip into a domain?